# Jersey 2 & HK2: any way to force a class reload for every request?

Tags: java, jersey, hk2

I wonder if there is an easy way to avoid having to use something like JRebel. Is there some useful way to make HK2 inject stuff using a clean class loader instance for each new request?

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered that one only needs to start the embedded jetty maven plugin using the eclipse debugger to have instant code replacement working... cool.